# Finding string position from a sorted list in a text file

Tags: combinations

This is something I've been working on. The characters A, B and C are used to generate all possible combinations of strings of length 17 characters such as ABCBCBAACBBCACBCB. This list is then sorted in such a way that the first string is AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA and the  very last one is CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC. How can we determine the position of a given string? For instance, a string like ABCBBBBCACBCACCCB appears at position number what in the sorted list?  I've generated all the combinations but the text file is so huge to even work with. I have also tried feeding that text data to a table in MySQL together with an auto_increment column but the queries seem to take eternity. Didn't even think of working with Microsoft Excel as it just won't do. What is the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Turn `A` into 0, `B` into 1, `C` into 2, then read the string in base 3.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get that. So, in order to find the position of CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC, this string becomes 22222222222222222 which I assume is decimal notation. Converting that to base 3 becomes 10222221011100200211000202100112000, which is very weird.

Comment: No, you need to convert *from* base 3.

Comment: Ah, yes, noted. Now it works perfectly. I've also noticed that after converting, I have to add a 1 to the result. For instance, CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC>>22222222222222222>>129140162+1=129140163. So CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC is at position 129140163